# Show elemens with delay on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to achieve the following:
when user hovers on list elements, I want to show hidden element inside a `<li>` with delay. For example, he hovers from red to violet, where he stops his mouse pointer. I don't want to show all hidden elements when user hovers through them, only the one where he stops.

```
<ul>
  <li>Red <div class="box red"></div></li>
  <li>Orane  <div class="box orange"></div></li>
  <li>Yellow  <div class="box yellow"></div></li>
  <li>Green  <div class="box green"></div></li>
  <li>Blue  <div class="box blue"></div></li>
  <li>Violet  <div class="box violet"></div></li>
</ul>
```

jquery

```
$("li").hover(function() {
$(this).children(".box").addClass("show");
}, function() {
$(this).children(".box").removeClass("show");
});
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/16region/q87dt9fe/35/

Comment: Do u want on hover it will show, upto hover the next div? Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and remove the jquery..

**css**

```
.box {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transition: 1s all ease 0s;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
li:hover .box {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: 1s all ease 0s;
}
```

Comment: Your method still shows elements above "violet", if I go from "red" to "violet" with my mouse.

Comment: That's y i asked the question? plz explain clearly.. If u hover the red the red will show.. the red will show, untill hover the next div.. is it correct?

Comment: If I hover red, the red should show only after 1 second or so, given mouse wasn't not moved from red hover area.